# Creating native playlist from a database of list of songs in android

Tags: android, database, media, native, playlist

This is the scenario:

- I have a database table that contains list of song titles along with album name, artist name and other info. The table is updated periodically from a web server.
- I have to display the song list in 3 ways; according to artist name, album name and song title.
- In album list, if user clicks on any album name, all the songs in the album must display on a sublist below the element.
- In artist list, if the user clicks on any artist, all the albums in the database should display below in sublist and so on.

So it's exactly like the default media playlist in Android.

I have looked into MediaStore.Audio.Playlists class but it looks like it generates playlist from media files while I have to generate from a list of song titles stored in a database. I have created a crude playlist but it's not that good so I'd prefer to use the native playlist if it's possible.

Any guidance on this?